# Doctrine not found entity id

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

i have a problem mapping entities in Doctrine 2 (with Symfony2). Symfony says that error is in Perfil entity, but the Doctrine section profiler says that the error is en Funcion entity.

This is the error (on the browser):

> The column id must be mapped to a field in class
>   AppsManantiales\CommonBundle\Entity\Perfil since it is referenced by a
>   join column of another class.

But, in the profiler:

> AppsManantiales\CommonBundle\Entity\Funcion: The referenced column
>   name 'id' has to be a primary key column on the target entity class
>   'AppsManantiales\CommonBundle\Entity\Funcion'. The referenced column
>   name 'id' has to be a primary key column on the target entity class
>   'AppsManantiales\CommonBundle\Entity\Perfil'.

This is the relation er:

[image]

The Perfil entity, basically is:

```
class Perfil implements RoleInterface{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=10)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $idperfil;

   /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Funcion", mappedBy="perfiles")
    * @ORM\JoinTable(name="perfil_funcion",
    *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="perfil", referencedColumnName="idperfil")},
    *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="funcion", referencedColumnName="idfuncion")}
    *  )
    */
    protected $funciones;

    // More code...
}
```

The Funcion entity basically is:

```
class Funcion {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=11)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $idfuncion;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Perfil", inversedBy="funciones")
     */
    protected $perfiles;

    // More code...
}
```

Any ideas ? Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

I think by default Doctrine relies on the convention that all primary keys in entities are represented by an attribute called `$id`. Two solutions :

- Rename your primary keys from `$idperfil` and `$idfuncion` to `$id` (which I recommend);
- Explicit the join criterion on your `Funcion` object on the `$perfiles` property:

  ```
  * @ORM\JoinTable(name="perfil_function"),
  *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="funcion", referencedColumnName="idfuncion")},
  *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="perfil", referencedColumnName="idperfil")}
  * )
  ```

Comment: Thanks, but add those lines and the error persist. So, delete "$perfiles" on "funcion" entity. Isnt important property.